# 404 Apache Tomcat with java and html

Tags: java, html, eclipse, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I am having when using apache tomcat with java. The problem might be in the web.xml but I dont know how to fix it. This is my project explorer:

[image]

So the thing is that when I run registro.html everything goes as expected:

[image]

But when I click on enviar the 404 appears:

[image]

So this is my code in registro.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Registro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/Ejer2/Registro" method="POST">
            <input type=hidden name=registro value=resultadoRegistro>
            <BR><BR>Username: <input type=text name=user>
            <BR><BR>Password: <input type=password name=pass>
            <BR><BR><input type=submit value="Enviar"><input type=reset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my Registro.java:

```
package Ejer2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.*;



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/Registro")
public class Registro extends HttpServlet implements SingleThreadModel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    public Registro() {
        super();

    }



    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session=req.getSession(true);
        Usuario miuser=(Usuario)session.getValue(session.getId());
        if(miuser==null){
            miuser=new Usuario(req.getParameter("user"),req.getParameter("password"));
            session.putValue(session.getId(),miuser);
        }
        res.setContentType("text/html");

        String user=req.getParameter("user");
        //String pass = req.getParameter("pass");

        PrintWriter toClient = res.getWriter();
        toClient.println("<html>");
        toClient.println("<title>REGISTRO REALIZADO</title>");
        toClient.println("Usuario "+user+" registrado con exito");
        toClient.println("</html>");

        toClient.close();
    }

}
```

And this my web.xml:

[image]

I don't know what to do, thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be a servlet2.5 project. As far as i know, servlet annotations are only supported since servlet3.0. Either use servlet3 or create a servlet mapping using a ``web.xml``.

Comment: where can i find a guide to make a web.xml mapping?

Comment: or where can i get the servlet 3.0?